# Go gorilla websocket write deadline

Tags: go

I am unable to understand this part of the code which uses `c.conn.SetWriteDeadline` function.

```golang
    // Time allowed to write a message to the peer.
    writeWait = 10 * time.Second

    // Time allowed to read the next pong message from the peer.
    pongWait = 60 * time.Second

    // Send pings to peer with this period. Must be less than pongWait.
    pingPeriod = (pongWait * 9) / 10

// A goroutine running writePump is started for each connection. The
// application ensures that there is at most one writer to a connection by
// executing all writes from this goroutine.
func (c *Client) writePump() {
    ticker := time.NewTicker(pingPeriod)
    defer func() {
        ticker.Stop()
        c.conn.Close()
    }()
    for {
        select {
        case message, ok := <-c.send:
            // LOGIC TO WRITE MESSAGE TO THE CONNECTION
        case <-ticker.C: 
            c.conn.SetWriteDeadline(time.Now().Add(writeWait)) //  ??
            if err := c.conn.WriteMessage(websocket.PingMessage, nil); err != nil {
                return
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am unable to wrap my head around the ticket channel logic. What are we trying to achieve here?

I am referring to the official docks for `go/gorilla/websocket` [here](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/blob/master/examples/chat/client.go#L114)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the SetWriteDeadline function documentation:

```
SetWriteDeadline sets the write deadline on the underlying network connection. 
After a write has timed out, the websocket state is corrupt and
all future writes will return an error. 
A zero value for t means writes will not time out.
```

So every ticker on the goroutine it is setting the write deadline to the current time plus whatever you have the writeWait const set to. The subsequent line then sends a ping message, with that deadline. This all happens on the ticker interval which is the const pingPeriod. The other go-routine, readPump(), should be setting a read deadline and handler for the pong message. This constant ping-pong keeps the connection alive according to the wait times you have set.